# Texture(AsyncDisplayKit)

Tags: swift, asyncdisplaykit

I am using Texture(AsyncDisplayKit) 
But i am facing one problem in below code

```
let videoNode = ASVideoNode()
```

Error is: Use of unresolved identifier 'ASVideoNode'

I used `pod "Texture"` for installation
And also added `#import <AsyncDisplayKit/AsyncDisplayKit.h>` in bridging header file.

What should be the reason for this error?

Comment: Never include code as a screenshot in your question. Include it as text using proper code formatting. Also include the error as text and point out which line is throwing that error.

Comment: ok.
Thanx for suggestion.

Comment: did you `import Texture` at the top of this file?, did you open the workspace file instead of project file after installing pods?

Comment: Texture Contains Objective-C files so i import in bridging header
`#import <AsyncDisplayKit/AsyncDisplayKit.h>`.

and i opened .workspace file only

Comment: I add this  `import  AsyncDisplayKit`
So, now it is working for me.
Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Your welcome, I'll add an answer so you can mark as closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the library.

`import AsyncDisplayKit`

Also make sure that you open the workspace and not the project file when using pods